# Should I start roselle in full sun?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, seeds, germination, hibiscus

I am starting roselle in seed trays with plain sterilised cocopeat and the temperature hovers around 24~40 degrees celsius each day, with atleast 6 hours of heavy sunlight here. Should I do this in full sun outside or in some shade?

Answer (score 1):

In shade - seedlings will just shrivel and keel over rapidly in full sun, you need to wait till they are little plants and growing well before giving them sunlight, and then do it gradually.

Answer (score 1):

Some shade is better. The reason being that while *Hibiscus sabdariffa* enjoys a long period of heat while growing and maturing, like all seedlings it has to go through a vulnerable stage where the radicle and shoot emerge and need to be kept moist otherwise they can dry out. As always avoid keeping the soil wet since this can encourage rot which is made worse by the oversupply of water in the soil displacing the beneficial oxygen in the soil-trapped air.

Comment: The cocopeat was a bit wet while planting. Is that a problem? Anything to do in such a case?